# I am doing Socket Programming With UDP PYTHON, how can i save client connected to the server, add that client to a list?

Tags: python, sockets, udp

i am using this code for
server:

```py
import socket

ip = "127.0.0.1"
localIP = "127.0.0.1"

localPort = 20001

bufferSize = 1024

msgFromServer = "Hello UDP Client"

bytesToSend = str.encode(msgFromServer)

# Create a datagram socket

UDPServerSocket = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

# Bind to address and ip

UDPServerSocket.bind((localIP, localPort))

print("UDP server up and listening")

# Listen for incoming datagrams

while (True):
    bytesAddressPair = UDPServerSocket.recvfrom(bufferSize)

    message = bytesAddressPair[0]

    address = bytesAddressPair[1]

    clientMsg = "Message from Client:{}".format(message)
    clientIP = "Client IP Address:{}".format(address)

    client = ip
    if localIP == ip:
        print(clientIP)
        print(clientMsg)
    else:
        print("ip not correct")

    # Sending a reply to client

    UDPServerSocket.sendto(bytesToSend, address)
```

CLIENT CODE:

```py
import socket
import time

count = 0
while count < 5:


    msgFromClient = "Hello"
    bytesToSend = str.encode(msgFromClient)


    serverAddressPort = ("127.0.0.1", 20001)

    bufferSize = 1024

# Create a UDP socket at client side

    UDPClientSocket = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

# Send to server using created UDP socket

    UDPClientSocket.sendto(bytesToSend, serverAddressPort)

    msgFromServer = UDPClientSocket.recvfrom(bufferSize)

    msg = "Message from Server {}".format(msgFromServer[0])

    print(msg)
    time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: Do you know how to make a list? Do you know how to put things in it?

Comment: No I don’t know how to make a list and how to put in list!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the client's IP is saved to the address variable. The list syntax in Python is the following:

```
listName = ["thing number 1", "thing number 2", 3, "and", 4]
```

To add entries to a list you use the .append() method

```
listName.append(address)
```

Best of luck

Comment: Daren Palmer thanks for reply, but i am facing problem in add more clients connected to server in list, with your above code only one client is getting save in list. i am trying like             print("-----------CLIENTS CONNECTED----------")
    CLIENTCONNECTED = [address,address]
    CLIENTCONNECTED.append(address)
    print(CLIENTCONNECTED)                                                      OUTPUT:-----------CLIENTS CONNECTED----------
[('127.0.0.1', 57680), ('127.0.0.1', 57680), ('127.0.0.1', 57680)]. HOW CAN I ADD MORE CLIENT IP ADDRESS IN LIST

Comment: ok, you should try saving the clients to an SQL database or, f you're just looking for an easier method, a .txt or .csv file. In python you can use this syntax: 
``with open("filename.extension", "w+") as file:
           file.write(str(address)+"\n")
           file.close()
 ``

Comment: i tired! when i am opening file its empty

Comment: Well that's weird, are you sure the address variable has a value?

Comment: with same coding i want to make a code that if new client is connects to server it give message its connected and we have added new client in list and if anyone of client disconnects it remove from list? can you help with this

Comment: Cool, if a solution worked don't forget to mark your question as answered!